# Remove a CLASS for all child elements

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="table-filters">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using table-filters as the jQuery selector, how can I clear out the elements having `CLASS=ACTIVE`, no matter which `LI` it happens to be on?

thanks

Answer (score 146, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#table-filters>ul>li.active").removeClass("active");
//Find all `li`s with class `active`, children of `ul`s, children of `table-filters`
```

Comment: the above solution is not working in chrome. so, I just changed it to $("#table-filters > li.active").removeClass("active");. Tq.

Answer (score 42):

You can also do like this :

```
  $("#table-filters li").parent().find('li').removeClass("active");
```

Comment: That is possible, but is way harder to process for jQuery, so if you're counting on a fast response you should use the above method. Also why would you select all 'li', then get the parent to find the 'li' and then remove the active class? Bit unproductive..

Comment: As i mentioned above, this is another way of doing it.

Comment: This is helpful for when the selector itself is too broad and you want to limit to the children of a single `parent` element.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('#table-filters ul li .active').removeClass('active');
```